# Send email to SMTP server on non-standard port

Tags: email, webmail

How can I email to a domain whose SMTP server does not listen on the standard port 25? I need to email to it through webmail, like GMail.

I thought this would work:
user@domain.com:port

Comment: i dont understand. why does the port matter if you are sending the email from a webmail client? If you are using a webmail client just send the email like normal. The client will take care of SMTP server settings. If you are trying to code an application you will either need an SMTP server to use or stand one up yourself in which case there will be settings that you will need to configure...one of which will be the port.

Comment: no the client doesn't know what port to connect to. this is not for an app, it's just for webmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with gmail. You need to configure a mail server to do this, and it's hard. The only other option is using a firewall to redirect traffic from 25 to your port.

(And this probably belongs on serverfault).